# How to use sed to remove all lines until first match in first column?

Tags: linux, sed

How to use sed to remove all lines until first match in first column? The result should keep the last three lines.

file

```
1fff
2ddd
3zzz

 TestXXX
 TestXXX
Test        XXX
Mike
Charly
```

sed -i '/Test/' file

Comment: Could You show an expected output too? It does sound like You haven't tried anything. Do space marks a new column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -n '/^Test/,$p' oldfile > newfile
```

Comment: faster than me :-) +1

Comment: well i was in a hurry to figure it out and use it :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the .. operator in perl
it toggles on when the first condition is met
and toggles off when the second is met.

(I've added ^ because you said you wanted the start of the line)

```
perl -nle 'print if /^Test/..0' file
```

LATE EDIT: on second reading, the ..0 isn't clear. it is the line number, and since line 0 will not be reached after "Test" it will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^Test/,$ p' YourFile
```

print only after your Test and until the end

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^Test/,$!d' file
```